# SQL Server 2000: select into case when in order by clause

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000, temp, case-statement, select-into

I am trying to select rows into a temporary table with a `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY` clause but records are not being sorted on insert.

```
Declare @orderby varchar(10) , @direction varchar(10)
set @orderby = 'col1'
set @direction = 'desc'
select identity (int) as autoid, *
into #temp
from table 
order by case when @direction = 'desc' and @orderby = 'co1' then col1 end desc

declare @startrow int
declare @maxrows int
set @starrow = 19
set @maxrow = 30
set rowcount @maxrows
select * from #temp 
where autoid > @startrow
```

Comment: It's absolutely pointless to try and insert into a temporary table in a specific order - when you want the rows back in a specific order, you'll need a specific `ORDER BY` anyway ..... so what are you trying to achieve, really?

Comment: I want to use this query for pagination.I will select from my temporary table and I need the autoid to be ordered by the column that is passed in as a parameter. I edited my question to have my final select statement.

Comment: You can do this from the original data - using a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER()` - no need to put that stuff into a separate temporary table first, just to paginate.....

Comment: I am using sql server 2000 which does not have the function row_number

Comment: I am also selecting from a long query. I  only posted the question using  a table as I did not think it was necessary to have the entire query here. basically my question is: Is there any way to select into a  temporary table ordering conditionally???

Comment: Not the way you're trying to do it, no. You'd have to build up a SQL query as a string, and then execute it (technique called *dynamic SQL*)

Comment: I noticed that your @OrderBy variable is varchar(10).  If your real code has column names greater than 10 characters, this would explain why you're not getting the correct sort.

Comment: Your "order by case" line has "@orderby = 'co1'" instead of "@orderby = 'Col1'"

Answer (score 1):

Worst case - you'll just have to use two separate SQL queries to achieve your goal:

```
if @direction = 'desc'
  select identity (int) as autoid, *
  into #temp
  from table 
  order by col1 desc

if @direction = 'asc'
  select identity (int) as autoid, *
  into #temp
  from table 
  order by col1 asc
```

Comment: the temp table can be sorted by six columns, and each can be can sorted asc or desc.I don't think I want to write 12 separate queries.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use multiple sort conditions in your order by clause to handle this properly.  The problem with this approach is that the performance will be bad when you have a lot of rows in the table because of that nasty sort operation.

Instead, you may be better off using dynamic SQL (as someone else suggested).

```
Declare @orderby varchar(100) , @direction varchar(10)
set @orderby = 'col1'
set @direction = 'desc'
select identity (int) as autoid, *
into #temp
from table 
order by case when @direction = 'desc' and @orderby = 'col1' then col1 end desc,
         case when @direction = 'asc'  and @orderby = 'col1' then col1 end,
         case when @direction = 'desc' and @orderby = 'col2' then col2 end desc,
         case when @direction = 'asc'  and @orderby = 'col2' then col2 end,
         case when @direction = 'desc' and @orderby = 'col3' then col3 end desc,
         case when @direction = 'asc'  and @orderby = 'col3' then col3 end,
         case when @direction = 'desc' and @orderby = 'col4' then col4 end desc,
         case when @direction = 'asc'  and @orderby = 'col4' then col4 end,
         case when @direction = 'desc' and @orderby = 'col5' then col5 end desc,
         case when @direction = 'asc'  and @orderby = 'col5' then col5 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this not using #temp tables insted use normal table temp. Later when you are done with your process you can drop it at the end.

```
declare @dir varchar(10)='desc'
DECLARE @str varchar(1000)
SET @str='select identity (int) as autoid,
* into temp from cust1 order by TransactionType '+@dir 
exec(@str)
select * from temp
```

Comment: Since he' using SQL Server 2000, this is **NOT** a valid option (see last comment)

Comment: oh yeah I did not see his last comment.I wil ry to get this in sql 2000